# Checking serial number on installer

Tags: php, ajax, json, installation, serial-number

I have a web app and I would like to protect it by having a serial number system.  This is all being dealt with via woocommerce and the software addon, the API docs are [here](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/user-guide/extensions/software-add-on/). This then generates a serial number when purchasing the script.

The only problem is how do I then check this from the web installer?

> Example code A WooCommerce powered shop using the Software Add On is
>   listening for API requests via the wc-api request set to software-api.
>   All API requests can be called like this:
>
> $data = wp_remote_get(
>   'http://localhost/woocommerce/?wc-api=software-api&request=request_key&...');
>   All parameters can be added to the URL. The data that the API returns
>   will be stored in the $data variable and is in JSON format.
>
> activation The activation API call is used to activate a single use of
>   a licence. The call has to contain the email address of the licence,
>   the key of the licence and the product id linked to the licence.
>
> Required params:
>
> request = ‘activation’ email licence_key product_id

The thing I don't understand is how to incorporate this into a text input on a form, and use ajax (maybe?) to check this step in the install? The example is for using a Wordpress function `wp_remote_get`, but the installer will not have this.

Comment: the api for this plugin is found at: http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/user-guide/extensions/software-add-on/